# How to enable LDAP authentication (Group level not user level) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ldap

I would like to enable LDAP group level authentication for PostgreSQL. Right now we are able to use LDAP to work with Active Directory Users directly. But we want to provide access to users by allowing their LDAP groups, so that each user in the group has access to the database

For example: I have DBA LDAP group, I want to add this group to the database in such a way that users in this group can access database when they try to login with their username.

this is working for LDAP user authentication:

```
host all all 10.0.0.0/8 ldap ldapscheme="ldaps" ldapserver=domain ldapbasedn="OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com" ldapbinddn="CN=bindaccount,OU=SA,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com" ldapbindpasswd="***" ldapsearchattribute="sAMAccountName"
```

I tried this for LDAP group authentication which is not working:

```
host all all 10.0.0.0/8 ldap ldapscheme="ldaps" ldapserver=domain ldapbasedn="OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com" ldapbinddn="CN=bindaccount,OU=SA,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com" ldapbindpasswd="***" ldapsearchattribute="(&(objectCategory=group)(sAMAccountName=DBA))"
```

Please let me know how this can be achievable in open source PostgreSQL.

Comment: Hm, that does not make much sense. if `sAMAccountName` is the user name, then `sAMAccountName` cannot be `DBA`, right? Can you edit the question and show all the attributes of the entry, plus which of those attributes determine the group?

Answer (score 0):

Is possible to grant permission for group instead individual user.. i have two groups in ldap.. (readers , editors) both account have more than 100 users..
how to authenticate all users under both groups in postgresql ?

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               ldap ldapserver="10.0.0.x" ldapprefix="CN=" ldapsuffix=",OU=dbusers,OU=editors,DC=mylab,DC=dev"